# Outter stroke is overlapping other characters

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Here's an example:

[image]

And here's an image I designed yesterday without that problem:

[image]

I didn't use any special process on the second image to keep the character strokes from overlapping things.

Comment: I'm guessing you outlined the text in the first one, but didn't in the second one.

Comment: To Dr. John Manly, actually, yeah, that was me.

Answer (score 7):

For live text, set your stroke and fill in the Appearance panel and make sure your fill is above the stroke by dragging it to the top.
[image: Appearance stroke and fill order]

If your type is outlined, you either need to apply the stroke to *the group* (you need to do this through the Appearance panel, otherwise the stroke is applied to each path individually).

Or you can create a compound path by selecting all of your outlined text and hitting
<kbd>cmd</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> (or **Object → Compound Path → Make**).

Comment: YES, compound path! Thank you!

Comment: thank you! bringing fill on top of stroke worked for me!